# Angular failed to instantiate - $locationProvider and $compileProvider causes errors

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to start an app, however 2 things are causing errors
`$locationProvider` and `$compileProvider` in my `config()` function ? But can't seem to figure out why?

I'm running **AngularJS v1.6.2**.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zerochili due to:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t
```

If I remove the `config`, the app runs without any problems...

The code:

```
import svg4everybody from 'svg4everybody';
import angular from 'angular';
import GlobalController from './Global/GlobalController';

let zeroChili = angular.module('zerochili', []);


zeroChili.config(function($locationProvider, $compileProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

// this increases performance significant
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
// to run debug in production, run this in console:
// angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
// see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production
});


zeroChili.controller('GlobalController', GlobalController);

function runApp() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['zerochili']);
}

runApp();
```

Comment: Can you try this:
`zeroChili.config(['$locationProvider', '$compileProvider', function($locationProvider, $compileProvider) { ...}]);`

Comment: Basically what he said, you need `$locationProvider` and `$compileProvider` referenced in brackets [ ] when declaring your module. Or use `$inject`.

Comment: It seemed to work :) Thx alot... How would one go about it if I were to use $inject?